# Ionic and FCM - Platform ready not fire and Error Domain

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I have to include FCM in my IONIC app. Before I added notification it works fine.
Android version works fine, but with iOS I have many problems.
I'm using [FCM plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/) but my app doesn't start.
That's my code:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  console.log('in ready..'); //i can't see this !!!!
  ...
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  fcm.subscribeToTopic('chats_public'); //fcm: FCM '@ionic-native/fcm'

});
```

}

When I try to build to device, I have this warning in Xcode console:

```
Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
```

and my app lock at splashscreen. At the first start up I got this also:

```
"Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 "(null)"
```

I have already read many post and I tried any solution:

- Enabled Capabilities "Push notification", "Background Modes (Remote notifications)" and "Keychain Sharing";
- I tried any Firebase Cloud messaging settings, with authentication key (.p8) or developer certificate (.p12);
- in Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties I add new properties FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnable = NO;

I have no idea how to solve it. it seems that it does not fire the "platform.ready()".

Comment: I solved removing plugin, node_modules and platform folders and reinstalling everythings. It is not a FCM problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking/checking Push notifications capability solved the problem, Xcode added a missing entitlement file to my project and it worked.

You need to change in below file :
    “AppDelegate+FCM”

Where you can find the below method:
    customDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Please replace below :

```
[FIRApp configure];

    with this

 // [START configure_firebase]
    if(![FIRApp defaultApp]){
        [FIRApp configure];
    }
```